# What should I use: on, at or another preposition... in "the wind blows....."?

Tags: prepositions

What should I use: on, at or another preposition... in the following sentence?

"The wind is blowing hard ____ my back".

Is there any difference if it's "my face" or "my body"?

By the way, can I use "block" in this: "He stood there, blocked the wind for me"? 
 (The wind was blowing in one direction)

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: How about the "ing" form? He stood there ***blocking*** the wind for me.

Comment: -1 which dictionary did you look up the prepositions in and why didn't those definitions answer your question?

Comment: It depends what you mean. Any of those three prepositions could work, as could dozens of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The wind is blowing hard **in** my back.

You need ***in*** there because the preposition ***in*** in English is used to describe the movement of something in a particular direction. Though, some might say that the preposition ***into*** would be, technically speaking, a better choice according to grammar books, but in real speech you will hear people say ***in*** all the time in situations like this one. ***on*** would mean that the wind is situated right on your back and is blowing there. That makes no sense. ***at*** is usually used to denote a situation where something is located at a particular point in space or time. This would have almost the same implication in meaning as in the example with ***on***, but is still acceptable. So, stick with ***in*** or ***into***.

Comment: -1 Absolutely not. *the wind is blowing hard  in my back* sounds ridiculous and connotes *the wind is blowing inside my back*.

Comment: No, the following is incorrect: "in real speech you will hear people say in all the time in situations like this one." You can't correct the wrong information you used in your first try by adding more incorrect information.

Comment: Please provide some uses of *in* in this context ("describe the movement of something in a particular direction").

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "at":

> The wind is blowing hard **at** my back.